# Only gettin Odd Rows for Blueimp Gallery while using Blueimp File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, gallery, blueimp

I have a custom implementation of [Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)'s [File](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) [Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and everything is going great save for one major flaw. The gallery part only makes a preview gallery of every *odd* row in my files table.

Keep in mind, as this is custom, and I simply hate templating engines, I'm not using the template layout. However rows are created pretty similar.

Example table after uploading several files:

```
<table id="tblFileUpload" role="presentation">
    <tbody class="files">
        <tr>
            <td class="td-thumb">
                <canvas width="51" height="75" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></canvas>
                <div class="preview-progress ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100">
                    <div class="preview-progress-label">Complete!</div><div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-name">
                <a href="http://68.67.73.249/jQueryFileUpload/server/php/files/Capture.PNG" target="_blank" data-gallery="data-gallery">Capture</a>
            </td>
            <td class="td-delete">
                <button class="delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" data-confirmation-name="Capture.PNG" data-type="DELETE" data-url="http://68.67.73.249/jQueryFileUpload/server/php/?file=Capture.PNG" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Remove">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
                    <span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-thumb">
                <canvas width="75" height="27" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></canvas>
                <div class="preview-progress ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100">
                    <div class="preview-progress-label">Complete!</div>
                    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-name"><a href="http://68.67.73.249/jQueryFileUpload/server/php/files/iamnew01.jpg" target="_blank" data-gallery="data-gallery">iamnew01</a>
            </td>
            <td class="td-delete">
                <button class="delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" data-confirmation-name="iamnew01.jpg" data-type="DELETE" data-url="http://68.67.73.249/jQueryFileUpload/server/php/?file=iamnew01.jpg" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Remove">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
                    <span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ...
```

It might also be worth noting I have been picking a part the gallery code itself, which appears similar too, but not *exact* same as [Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery)'s [Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) [Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery), and I have noticed, the last function yields far different results for variables a-i on mine than on the test page. I also get the following error:

> GET http://[ip]/jQueryFileUpload/img/play-pause.svg 404 (Not Found)

### Example of Blueimp's test return on last function of Gallery

```
a function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:776
b function b(a, c) {
        return a && a.length && void 0 !== document.body.style.maxHeight ? this && this.options === b.prototype.options ? (this.list = a, this.num = a.length, this.initOptions(c), this.initialize(), void 0) : new b(a, c) : null
    } jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:777
c 
x.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1389982738769, jQuery110202015542311128229: true…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:778
d  jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:779
e 
[jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:780
f 
[div#blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery-controls, context: document, selector: "#blueimp-gallery", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:781
g 
Object {onopen: function, onopened: function, onslide: function, onslideend: function, onslidecomplete: function…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:782
h 
Object {filter: ":even", container: div#blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery-controls, index: a, event: x.Event, onopen: function…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:783
i 
[a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "[data-gallery=""]", jquery: "1...
```

### Mine

```
a function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:776
b function b(a, c) {
        return a && a.length && void 0 !== document.body.style.maxHeight ? this && this.options === b.prototype.options ? (this.list = a, this.num = a.length, this.initOptions(c), this.initialize(), void 0) : new b(a, c) : null
    } jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:777
c 
b.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1389982647710, jQuery19106168011745903641: true…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:778
d  jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:779
e 
[jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:780
f 
[div#blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery-controls, context: document, selector: "#blueimp-gallery", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:781
g 
Object {onopen: function, onopened: function, onslide: function, onslideend: function, onslidecomplete: function…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:782
h 
Object {filter: ":even", container: div#blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery.blueimp-gallery-controls, index: a, event: b.Event, onopen: function…}
 jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:783
i 
[a, a, a, a, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: "[data-gallery=""]", jquery: "1...
```

Any idea's from anyone familiar with these two plugins why my extremely similar layout wouldn't result in the exact same Gallery/Slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your html of id blueimp-galley has something as:   data-filter=":even"

Comment: ah shoot, this was already so long and so much work agao, i dont even remember what I was doing with this, like what job it was, lol